# Include tag in TWIG

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am trying to use include tag in questionanswer Twig page for including the entity (queId) of resource twig page but i am getting error :

questionanswer.html.twig :

```
        {% for entity in entities %}
        <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ path('questionanswer_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.id }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ entity.question }}</td>
        <td>{{ entity.answer }}</td>
        <td>
        {% if entity.getResource is empty %}
        <p> </p>
        {% else %}                        
        <a href="{% include 'SymfonySymfonyBundle:resource:index.html.twig' with { 'id': entity.queId } %}">Yes</a>
        {% endif %}
        </td>
```

Unable to return the foreign key (queId) from resource entity  into questionanswer twig .

questionAnswer entity:

```
            /**
             * @var ArrayCollection
             * 
             * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="resource", mappedBy="queId")
             */

            private $resources;

            /**
             * Get resources
             *
             * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
             */
            public function getResources() {
            return $this->resources->toArray();
```

resouce Entity:

```
            /**
             * @var integer
             * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="questionanswer", inversedBy="resources")
             * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="que_id", referencedColumnName="id")
             */
            private $queId;
```

Comment: What if you make it `public` instead of `private`?

Comment: The getter is public

Comment: Can you provide queId getter source?

Answer (score 2):

the method is named `getResources` in your object, but you use `getResource` (notice the singular) in your template